# Automatically add shorter (posix) argument in argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I have the following code:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Dedupe library.', allow_abbrev=True)
parser.add_argument( '-a', '--all', nargs='+', type=int, help='(Optional) Enter one or more IDs.')
```

Is it possible to automatically add in the `-a` option when it's not specified? For example, something like:

```
parser.add_argument('--all', nargs='+', type=int, help='(Optional) Enter one or more IDs.')
```

And it can be called with:

```
$ parse.py -a 2
$ parse.py --all 2
```

Or is that not an option with argparse?

Comment: That seems like a dangerous thing to ask for - you're going to end up with multiple long options competing for the same short option, or long options "claiming" a short option you didn't want them to claim just because you forgot to turn this "feature" off.

Comment: Just define your own wrapper function for it?

Comment: Particularly, you say "posix" in your title, but POSIX-specified short option names are very frequently *not* the first letter of the common long option name. For example, going down the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) for GNU ls, the thing you're asking for would hurt more often than it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A clean way to do something like this, is by subclassing `ArgumentParser` and creating your own:

```
import argparse


class MyArgumentParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    def add_argument(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # check if one was already passed, for backward compatibility
        if not any(len(a) == 2 and a.startswith('-') for a in args):
            for a in args:
                if a.startswith('--'):
                    # you could do something more fancy here, like calling an (optional) callback
                    return super().add_argument(a[1:3], *args, **kwargs)
        return super().add_argument(*args, **kwargs)


parser = MyArgumentParser(description='Dedupe library.', allow_abbrev=True)
parser.add_argument('--all', nargs='+', type=int, help='(Optional) Enter one or more IDs.', dest='all')
```

Mind you, it's not necessarily a good idea. You can have conflicting options (like multiple that start with the same letter, so you might need to add code for that). And then you may have a preference for which option takes which letter with many options. Etc.

In the end, you have to ask yourself if the "convenience" offered by a solution like this really outweighs the effort of writing it, the overhead of the extra code and the lack of clarity in the resulting code for future you and other contributors that wonder where the extra options are coming from. Not to mention that it's perhaps just a good thing to explicitly state what options you're setting up?

Just that something can be done, doesn't mean you should do it.